# How to read in numerous csv files and calculate boxplot stats for each?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, boxplot, quantile

I have a directory containing around 10 csv files, all huge datasets with 50M+ rows. I want to create a for loop to

- read them in one by one
- calculate boxplot stats using the quantile function for each dataset
- concatenate those stats to one dataframe

Any idea on how I could do so?

Here's how I expect the resulting df to look, columns consisting of features and the probability quantiles.

```
features  25%   50%   75%
Age       24     28    35
Height    161   175   194
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? This sounds like a task that could be broken out into smaller sub-tasks, then if you run into an issue at any given point, you can ask a question with a [mcve] and get more specific help

Answer (score 0):

Explore [pandas read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), and [pandas quantile](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) functions.

For example, you might have have something like the following:

```py
quantiles = [.25, .50, .75]
results = OrderedDict([(x,[]) for x in quantiles])
columns = ["age", "height"]

for csv_file in os.listdir(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(file_path, csv_file))
    for column in columns:
        for value in quantiles:
            results[value].append(df[column].quantile(value))

result_df = pd.DataFrame(data=results, index=columns)
```

You may need to use the chunksize param to deal with memory management when reading in the files.